# (C) what ways can we manipulate memory length and addresses?

Tags: c

im having a tough time proposing this question to alot of people. if anyone here can help me shed some light on this i would greatly appreciate as this has been the ultimate road block for almost three years with my problem.

if you know your arrays and memory than skip the the last paragraph for the big question, but if you read through this it may help you understand why and with what concepts i am struggling to grasp.

so we have an initialized array

```
    int main(){
    int x=10;
    int arr[x]={3,5,1,9,4,17,2,12,6,8};
```

to access the 5th element of the array, we would print it out as follows

```
    printf("%d",arr[4]);
```

now, my first question revolves around this process. the printf function defines that i want to print an integer, and as a directory, i give it the array name/address of first element and specify that i would like the 4th element of the array.

the information i have so far leads me to believe that each integer occupies 4 bytes of memory. usually, in a classroom setting when a professor explains this they draw this on the board

```
       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
    [1000][1004][1008][1012][1016][1020][1024][1028][1032][1036]
    {  3    5     1     9     4     17    2     12    6      8  }
```

now, this is all basic but during my time in learning how computers work ive realized one very important thing, computers are very stupid and that is why we program them, so please bear with me.

question 1: is this an accurate representation of memory? this is how almost everyone on youtube, in classrooms, etc. paints the picture, a sequential list starting at 1000 and increasing by +4, what if i have two arrays of the same size? they cant occupy the same memory addresses so how can i keep track of the where.

question 2: i understand that arr[4]; refers to the value of the 4th position of the array. but this arr[4], what is it? the 4. is this 4 stored in memory somewhere? what data type is this 4? is it a pointer as well? my understanding is that it is an extension of the pointer array, which confuses me. because the array points to the the 1st element in position 0, how does a pointer "4" coexist inside of a pointer? what does the process look like for the computer? im assuming its not a problem because 4 is a pointer argument and can therefore exist within the indicated array pointer.

but the process? is it, go to arr[0] and then count 4 bytes from position 0 4 times? what address does position 0 hold? i know for teaching purposes its visualized as starting at 1000 but is that always the case? why not address 1036 and count 4 up from there? i know i read somewhere that memory addresses compartmentalize storage by making sure if a char (1 byte) is stored in memory next to an int (4 bytes) then there are gaps of memory between to make it all a divisible of 2.

so now on to my final question, which i cant find anything on the interwebz about. can i somehow tell the computer to assign the length of memory from index 0 - n to a variable? maybe im asking in the wrong way, so let me rephrase. is there a data type that defines length of memory and not position? i know we can access the amount of memory a certain variable is taking, but to do that we reference the variable and receive the memory as a result. i want to assign a length of memory to a variable.

Comment: I think you should ask your teacher - that is what they are paid to do.

Comment: This question is probably Too Broad for Stack Overflow. One thing that would probably help you is to learn a little assembly language (maybe for a simple microcontroller, maybe for x86). Understanding what the C code compiles into will make the way the C code works make a lot more sense.

Comment: NOTE: your making the assumption that the underlying hardware architecture is 32 bit.  Depending on the specific CPU it could be 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit.  And note that with an OS, it is a virtual address that you get with `&array[4]`  And `array[4]` refers to the 5 element in the array because in C arrays are indexed over the range 0...(number of elements in array -1).  So `array[4]` is referencing the 5th element in the array

Comment: regarding: *i give it the array name/address of first element and specify that i would like the 4th element of the array*. Not quite true. Actually the function printf() is receiving the contents of the fifth element in the array

Comment: regarding: *is there a data type that defines length of memory and not position?*  You might want to look at the function: `strlen()` and similar.  Also read about how math operations on addresses are actually handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a data type that defines length of memory and not position?

ALL data types in C do this.  Every type defines how many bytes are needed to hold that type and what the individual bits in each byte mean.  This is implementation defined, so different compilers and different targets define them differently, but the language gives you the tools to write portable code that will work in a well-defined manner whatever that may be.

- sizeof tells you the size of any type in bytes.  so `sizeof(int)` will tell you how large an `int` is on your target -- generally 4, but some targets use 8 or 2.
- `CHAR_BIT` tells you the size of a byte -- how many bits are in a byte.  You don't often need this, but when you do, it is available.